# paypal buy now button with redirection after success

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I am creating a website where there will be a lot of digital products with variety of product prices. I went to paypal and created a button.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="W6HILXXVHKYZBY">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

They price is predefined when creating the button. And also I want the users to be redirected to a `success` in my website after the payment is complete. The above code works in `live` environment but in sandbox it gives error. PLUS it is not what I require.

I want something like this

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">  
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="accounts@mydomain.com">  

    <strong>How much do you want to pay?</strong><br />  
    $ <input type="text" name="amount" value="30" readonly="readonly">  

    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">  
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">  
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">  
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">  
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://net.mydomain.com/payment-complete/">  

    <br /><br />  
    <input type="submit" value="Pay with PayPal!">  

</form>
```

Everything in this code works, but it wont redirect to my `success` page automatically.

Answer (score 3):

There are some conditions for it to work correctly. you can read them here on the [PayPal Developers website](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/ProfileAndTools/#id08A9E900IEX).

**Here is the Note from PayPal about Auto Return:**

> If you have turned on Auto Return and have chosen to turn on PayPal Account Optional for new users, a new user will not be automatically directed back to your website, but will be given the option to return.
>
> The Return URL will be applied to all of your Auto Return payments unless otherwise specified within the button or link for that Website Payment. You may specify a different Return URL by changing it in your profile settings; otherwise, you may add or edit the HTML (variable: return) associated with a button or link. In this case, the Return URL that is associated with the button or link will override what was specified in the profile settings.

Comment: That is true, but it won't redirect automatically if the user is signed out (old checkout form of PayPal). Then user has to manually press on "Return to business"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `live` account credentials are different from `sandbox` credentials. Check that you are using the right account email.
Secondly, as Prakash-GPz said, you should enable auto return in your sandbox account also in order to be redirected to success page.